# How can I choose when to synchronize a word document with OneDrive?

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive, microsoft-onedrive

I have a folder to synchronize with OneDrive. I want to make local changes on a word document in this folder without updating the copy on OneDrive each time I do so. I want to maintain and update a local version, and decide when the OneDrive copy needs to be updated.
How can I do this?

Now when I modify the local version, the OneDrive copy is also modified.

Comment: Disable auto-save and enable it when your ready to synchronize the changes

Comment: I agree with the above.  Also consider a 3rd party sync App that you can run on demand.

Comment: But if i disable auto-save it won't be saved at all, am I wrong? What if I lose all the changes? I would like to have a local copy saved